# Postgresql result based on condition

Tags: postgresql, select, conditional-statements

I'm not sure if problem title is correct. I will describe problem.

I have sql  query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE condidtion_1 or condition_2;
```

table has got element that can match `condition_1` or `condition_2`. It is possible in some way that:

1. if elements match `condition_1` then we return only that elements and don't check for elements that match `condition_2`
2. if not match `condition_1` then we return only that element that match `condition_2`
3. if not match `condition_1` and `condition_2` then don't return anything (normal way)

Thanks for advice.

**EDIT**

Gordon answer inspired me to test something like that and looks that is working ok, but maybe some other more clear solution?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (condition_1 AND NOT condition_2) OR (NOT condition_1 AND condition_2);
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why is this different from a regular OR? What do you mean by elements - records? Or columns? Can you post a couple of sample records and the desired result?

Comment: OR will return rows that match condition_1 OR condition_2. Look for my update. I think that clarify all.

Comment: Ah, you mean "exclusive OR". Your answer works, but so does Gordon's if you put brackets around the first "OR" statement...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (condition_1 or condition_2) and
      not (condition_1 and condition_2);
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. Maybe I wrong define problem but, condition_1 can return another results than condition_2. I will update problem to clarify that.

Comment: Updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Compare results of conditions directly

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (condition_1) != (condition_2)
```